# Linq and List of Lists

Tags: c#, linq

Important: I want to do this using Linq.

I have a list of Devices in which there is a list of Options. Lets say there are 5 devices and every device has several options in it.

Now I need to get all the devices whose Option's Name contains "Foot Pedal" and its installation is set to "true".

Thanks

The code goes like this:

```
public class Device
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean Installed { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceTest
{
    public DeviceTest()
    {
        List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
        Option option;
        Device device;

        device = new Device();
        device.ID = 1;
        device.Name = "WC-1";
        devices.Add(device);

        device.Options = new List<Option>();
        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1001;
        option.Name = "Foot pedal";
        option.Installed = true;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1002;
        option.Name = "Wheel";
        option.Installed = true;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        device = new Device();
        device.ID = 2;
        device.Name = "WC-2";
        devices.Add(device);

        device.Options = new List<Option>();
        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1003;
        option.Name = "Foot pedal";
        option.Installed = true;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1004;
        option.Name = "Wheel";
        option.Installed = true;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        device = new Device();
        device.ID = 3;
        device.Name = "WC-3";
        devices.Add(device);

        device.Options = new List<Option>();
        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1005;
        option.Name = "Foot pedal";
        option.Installed = false;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1006;
        option.Name = "Wheel";
        option.Installed = true;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        device = new Device();
        device.ID = 4;
        device.Name = "WC-4";
        devices.Add(device);

        device.Options = new List<Option>();
        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1007;
        option.Name = "Foot pedal";
        option.Installed = false;
        device.Options.Add(option);

        option = new Option();
        option.ID = 1008;
        option.Name = "Wheel";
        option.Installed = false;
        device.Options.Add(option);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward query:

```
allDevices.Where(d => d.Options.Any(o => o.Name == "Foot Pedal" && o.Installed));
```

Remember that a lambda is just a function. It can call other functions, declare variables, and everything else you can do in normal code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetDevices = devices.Where(i => i.Options.Any(j => j.Installed && j.Name == "Foot pedal")).ToList()
```

or

```
var targetDevice = 
  (from device in devices 
   from option in device.Options
   where option.Installed && option.Name == "Foot pedal"
   select device).ToList()
```

Note the ToList() at the end, if the result is null, this will return a empty list instead of null.